# How to test bean property in Struts 2?

Tags: struts2, ognl

I have a class like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public boolean isValid() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In my JSP file I want to use the `isValid` method in a test condition:

```jsp
<s:bean name="com.Foo" var="bar"></s:bean>
<s:if test="%{bar.valid == false}">
    <p>hello</p>                    
</s:if>
```

but it doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean? Does it have any exception or error?

Comment: There is no error, the "hello" just doesn't show up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Context variables are referenced by `#`, but you've used a name `bar` without number sign.

```jsp
<s:if test="%{#bar.valid == false}">
    <p>hello</p>                    
</s:if>
```

---

Look at the [Variable References](https://commons.apache.org/dormant/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Variable_References) of the OGNL language guide.

> OGNL has a simple variable scheme, which lets you store intermediate
> results and use them again, or just name things to make an expression
> easier to understand. All variables in OGNL are global to the entire
> expression. You refer to a variable using a number sign in front of
> its name, like this:
>
> ```regex
> #var
> ```

Comment: Struts 2.5.2 uses OGNL 3.1.10 dependency.